# Laravel 8 Queue Connection not configured although my queue working fine, but generate log in laravel.log file in every second

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Laravel 8 queue working fine, but every second generate log in storage/laravel.log file is : The [database--queue=default] queue connection has not been configured. {"exception":"[object]
(InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The [database--queue=default] queue connection has not been configured

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you configure your driver properly in the configs/queue.php, for example:

```
  'connections' => [
        'database' => [
            'driver'      => 'database',
            'table'       => 'jobs',
            'queue'       => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],
   ]
```